# Shorten my jQuery Toggle script

Tags: jquery, toggle

Hi I have a toggle script that works on #toggleshow for the trigger and #show for the div that displays.

I am using multiple instances of this so I have a script that suffixes numbers at the end of the ID. So I have #toggleshow01, #show01 and so forth.

My script that runs this function is:

```
$('#toggleshow').live('click', function() {$('#show').slideToggle('slow', function() {});});
```

The problem is I have to duplicate this script for each instance, ie

```
    $('#toggleshow').live('click', function() {$('#show').slideToggle('slow', function() {});});
    $('#toggleshow00').live('click', function() {$('#show00').slideToggle('slow', function() {});});
    $('#toggleshow01').live('click',function() {$('#show01').slideToggle('slow', function() {});});
    $('#toggleshow02').live('click',function() {$('#show02').slideToggle('slow', function() {});});
    $('#toggleshow03').live('click',function() {$('#show03').slideToggle('slow', function() {});});
```

These are the variables I am using to generate the suffixes

```
var numToggle = 0;
var numShow = 0;        
var toggleTrigger = $('<a id="toggleshow'+ "0" + numToggle++ +'" class="toggle_trigger actions">&nbsp;</a>');
var menuForm = $('<form id="menu_edit_form'+ "0" + numForm++ +'" class="menu_creation_form"></form>');
```

Please help me to cut this script down to one line if possible.

Comment: You could do a whole lot better by just adding a class to all those `#toggleshow` elements and navigating to their sister `#show` inside the event handler. *Then* you could do an one-liner. But the exact solution depends on the HTML layout. And why are you using `live`?

Comment: Hi, That sounds good, I am using live because the toggle function was not working without it. I have quite a complicated thing going on, you can look at the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/edmCZ/4/ I didnt post it eariler because I was trying to keep the question simple. Cheers

Comment: Hi guys, here is the fiddle I am working on, sorry I didnt post it earlier but it quite daunting and I wanted to keep the question simple. Cheers. http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/edmCZ/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally hate doing things like "`toggleshowX`" mapping to "`showX`".  We have much better ways to store data these days.  You could for example have your links look like this:

```
<a class="toggle_trigger actions" data-target="#show00">&nbsp;</a>
```

This allows you to get the target based on relevant information using `$(this).data('target')` in the callback.

```
$('.toggle_trigger').live('click', function() {
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $(target).slideToggle('slow', function() {});
});
```

In one line of code:

```
$('.toggle_trigger').live('click', function() {$($(this).data('target')).slideToggle('slow', function() {});});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks this theory sounds way better than using two IDs but I implemented it, got the target to correspond with the #show but the toggle function doesn't trigger. This is the fiddle I am working on http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/edmCZ/4/ all the functions are at the bottom of the script section, there is a big ass plugin on top

Comment: Hi, it does work now, sorry I did a typo error before but when I close it, it opens and closes 3 times now. Any idea why this happens? Thanks

Comment: Can you post your latest jsfiddle so I can see how it is working?

Comment: Sure thing, it'll only be on Monday though because the code is at work. Cheers

Comment: Hi, here is the fiddle with your code working, but opening multiple times. It works perfectly on the first one though. Cheers http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/edmCZ/7/

Comment: Your problem is that you are adding a `live` event listener each time you add an item.  You should only add a `live` event listener once per selector. jQuery will monitor for DOM changes and attach the event accordingly.  See http://jsfiddle.net/edmCZ/8/

Comment: Thanks that works great but I can't see where you have removed the live event listener. Would you mind pointing it out to me? Thanks

Comment: I just took the event listeners you were adding on click and moved them outside of the click listener.  If you search for "live" you should spot them.

Comment: No worries, I found the difference, the closing tag moved, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give each "toggleShow" a class of "toggleShow" (for example: `<div class="toggleShow">`). Then each each "show" a class of "show". Then you can easily do:

`$(".toggleShow").live("click", function() {$(".show", this).slideToggle("slow");});`

I'll be honest and say I haven't tested it, but it should work well.

EDIT:

Formatted for easier reading:

```
$(".toggleShow").live(
  "click", 
  function() {
    $(".show", this).slideToggle("slow");
  }
);
```

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I assumed "show" was a child of "toggleShow". Woops. Ignore this.

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
$(id^='toggleshow').live('click', function() {
    $suffix = this.attr('id').substr(10);
    $('#show'+$suffix).slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: Hi, sorry tried this but it doesn't trigger the toggle function. Thanks

Comment: @Clinton - Sorry, I screwed up the intial selector.  Try it now.

Comment: Thanks man, I'll have to wait till Monday, all the code is at work but I'll def give it a bash. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks I tried this again but it didn't work out. Here is the original fiddle that I am working on. The toggle script I am currently using is right at the bottom of the js window. Cheers. http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/edmCZ/4/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it in a single line. There are also probably better ways to do this than using `live()`, but I cleaned up your logic a bit and made it a little more maintainable. I also don't have your HTML or any idea what you are trying to accomplish so take this with a grain of salt.

```
        (function () {
           $(document).ready(function () {
               var items = new Array(),
                   idprefix = "toggle";

               for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                   items.push("show0" + i);
               }
               $.each(items, function () {
                   $('#' + idprefix + this).live('click', function () {
                       $('#' + this).slideToggle('slow');
                   });
               });
           })
       })()
```